# Powershell script to add a field to all the document sets

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, powershell, column

I have created a field in sharepoint content type hub. Now I want to add this field to all the Document Libraries in my sharepoint online tenant.

Is there a powershell script which can do this for me?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a column or a content type in the content type hub? If it is a column, did you add it to the Document Library content type?

If that is the case, you can either wait for propagation of the change or you can choose Republish option under Content type>>Manage publishing for this content type
[image]

If you have created a new content type, that content type is already propagated to a site collection level, and want to add it to specific lists (document library is a list), you can use this Powershell script:
[Add Content Type to Task Lists](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Add-Content-Type-to-Task-253d3966)
and modify it so that it chooses  `if($ll.BaseTemplate -eq 101)` instead of  `if($ll.BaseTemplate -eq 107 -or $ll.BaseTemplate -eq 171)`

Comment: I have created a new field. Now I should be able to add this field to all the existing document libraries(Lists) on site-collection.

Comment: Site columns only get pushed out from the content type hub when they are attached to a content  type. If you create the column on the hub, it won't get exported until it's attached to a content type which is published. So you cannot use only a column from content type hub on other site collections.